# Is there a way to use an account for FileVault2 volume-decryption without logging it on?

Tags: macos, filevault, login, login-screen

I recall a key-combination, in a pre-Mavericks OSX, that could be pressed after entering one account's info for initial startup FileVault volume decryption. The key-combo prevented a full login of that account, instead dropping again to the login prompt, for login via another account.

However, I can no longer find any reference to this capability, nor re-discover the combination through trial-and-error.

Does this option still exist? It was convenient.

(Of course, I can immediately log-off that FileVault account. But in addition to that extra step, when next logging-into my real work account, I never get the question that allows cancelling the annoying re-opening of all apps open at the last crash.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of the key-combination.
However, here's how I did this on Mavericks (10.9.2):

- Click **System Preferences**
- Click **Users & Groups**
- If the **Lock** icon is closed, click the **lock** icon and authenticate
- Click **Login Options**
- Locate **Network Account Server** and click **Edit** (if there is a network server) or **Join** (if there is not)
- Click **Open Directory Utility**
- If the **Lock** icon is closed, click the **lock** icon and authenticate
- Click **Directory Editor** icon
- Search for the user you want to restrict
- Click the user name
- Expand **Authentication Authority**
- Click the <kbd>+</kbd> - to the right of Authentication Authority, not the one at the bottom of the window!
- Change new value to `;UserDisabled;`
- Click **Save**

The user can unlock the FileVault, but cannot login.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to set the FileVault 2 login process on Mavericks so that you're stopped at the OS login window after logging in at the FileVault 2 login window.

The way to do this is to disable FileVault 2's automatic login, which is the process that the OS uses to automatically log you into your account after you've logged in at the FileVault 2 pre-boot login screen. Apple has a KBase article here that shows how to do this:

[OS X: How to disable automatic login when FileVault is enabled](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5989)

After that, reboot your Mac and login at the FileVault 2 pre-boot login screen using your non-work account's password. When the OS unlocks and boots, you should then be stopped at the OS login window. At that point, login with your work account's username and password.